# GLSL array uniform with a dynamic length

Tags: arrays, three.js, glsl

I'm trying to implement a "fog of war" feature into my strategy game. I've been reading some other Q&A on SO and I figured that I need to use custom GLSL shaders. So I defined and array containing "vision points":

```
let vision_points = [
  new THREE.Vector2(1500, 1500),
  new THREE.Vector2(1500, -1500),
  new THREE.Vector2(-1500, 1500),
  new THREE.Vector2(-1500, -1500)
]
```

And used `ShaderMaterial` passing in the vision points as a uniform. Since the arrays length might be any value, I inject `VPOINTSMAX` constant at the beginning of the vertex shader code:

```
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    u_texture: {type: 't', value: this.texture},
    vision_points: {
      type: 'v2v',
      value: vision_points
    }
  },
  vertexShader: "#define VPOINTSMAX "+vision_points.length+"\n"+fow_vs,
  fragmentShader: fow_fs
});
```

Then the vertex shader calculates the distance between the vertex itself and each vision_point. Then it sets a `varying float in_vision` to 0.0 or 1.0, depending if the vertex is in vision range:

```
uniform vec2 vision_points[VPOINTSMAX];

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying float in_vision;

void main() {
  in_vision = 0.0;
  for (int v = 0; v < VPOINTSMAX; v++) {
    vec2 pos2 = vec2(position.x, position.z);
    float distance = length(pos2-vision_points[v]);
    if (distance < 1000.0) {
      in_vision = 1.0;
    } 
  }
  // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
  v_texCoord = uv;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                  vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Lastly the fragment shader darkens the color if in_vision value is not more than 0:

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying float in_vision;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
  if (in_vision > 0.0) {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = color/2.0;
  }
}
```

And so I got the result I wanted:
[image]

Now the problem is that, while the game will be running, the contents of `vision_points` array will be changing as well as its length. There shouldn't be any trouble changing the uniform value, but as the length of array will be changing, I need to find a way to redefine the `VPOINTSMAX` constant. The only solution that I could think of so far is reconstructing the `ShaderMaterial` and recompiling the shader code with a new `VPOINTSMAX` value injected. Then simply applying a new material to the mesh. But I fear that this might cause performance issues.

**What other approaches would you suggest for updating/passing an array with a dynamically changing length into the GLSL shader as a uniform?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make multiple `ShaderMaterial`s, one for each number of `VPOINTSMAX` you want to support. Change the material on the `Mesh`s when you want to use a different `VPOINTSMAX`

GLSL does not support variable sized arrays.

The only other solution is to set `VPOINTSMAX` to the largest size you'll ever use and then break out of your for loop as on

```
uniform int maxPoints;

#define VPOINTSMAX 20

...
  for (int v = 0; v < VPOINTSMAX; v++) {
    if (v >= maxPoints) {
     break;
    }
    ...
  }
```

But that seems like it would be slower since loops are often unrolled in GPUs