# Passing Integer to Shader to Define Array Length ( ThreeJS )

Tags: arrays, three.js, int, glsl

I wanna pass an integer value to a shader to define the length of an array.  I pass it like this:

```
uniforms:{
    num_parcels: { value: ap_props.parcels }
}
```

ap_props.parcels = 24.  I receive it in the shader and try to apply it like this:

```
uniform int num_parcels;
uniform vec3 air_parcel_position[ num_parcels ];
```

I see this error in the browser console:

THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:123: '' : constant expression required
ERROR: 0:123: '' : array size must be a constant integer expression

I tried converting num_parcels to a constant, but it doesn't seem to be allowed.

**Is there anyway I can pass an integer to a shader and use it to define the length of an array?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLSL array uniform with a dynamic length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519961/glsl-array-uniform-with-a-dynamic-length)

Comment: I think my question and answer is more direct and simple but perhaps..

Answer (score 0):

I apologize.  I figured out how to do this.  Here's how to pass an integer to a shader to define an array length:

```
var velocityShader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms:{
        time: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        bounce: { type: 'f', value: .5 },
        friction: { type: 'f', value: .99 },
        gravity: { type: 'f', value: .1 }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'ortho-vs' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: "#define NUM_PARCELS " + ap_props.parcels + "\n" + document.getElementById( 'velocity-fs' ).textContent,
    depthTest: false,
    depthWrite: false
} );
```

**The line that begins with fragmentShader is the answer.**

Comment: `ShaderMaterial` has a `defines` property for that purpose. Also, `type:` is not needed. three.js r.104

Comment: Yea, you commented about the type: in another thread of mine here.  I just haven't gotten around to cleaning up the code.  I do understand how it works now though.  Thank you.