# Compute shaders : How do you pass not-so-regular structures as parameters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, compute-shader

I am working in C#, with Unity.
I have created a compute shader to which I want to pass my array of C# data structures.
That's when I realized I might have gone overboard with fancy data structures, instead of sticking to the C-like structures of shaders.

More specifically, I'm hitting two road blocks:

**1. Each of the objects I want to pass to the shader's buffer contains a linked list,** which means the size varies between objects. Can the shader buffer be defined as anything else than an array with its size passed explicitly?

**2. Each of the objects I want to pass to the shader is polymorphic.** i.e. they all have a field "type", but then if type==0 they have a field value0, while the ones with type==1 have a field value1. Is it reasonable to try and achieve that in shaders language (with a C-like union maybe)?

```
interface IObject {
   public int type { get; }
}

class Type0 : IObject {
   public int type => 0;
   public int field0;
}

class Type1 : IObject {
   public int type => 1;
   public float field1;
}

class ItemForShader {
   public List<IObject> objects { get; set; }
}
...

// Can I pass this to the shader?
var shaderParameters = new List<ItemForShader>() {
    new ItemForShader() {
       objects = new() { new Type0(), new Type1() }
    },
    new ItemForShader() {
       objects = new() { new Type1(), new Type0(), new Type0() }
    }
}
```

Please note : I don't need you to detail any solution at length (I can already see you describe how to pass a shared pool of linked-list nodes and then share those nodes between all the objects with a fancy indexing system).

**I simply want to know what's reasonable and how it's usually done (or not done).** Maybe describe in essence what C structure matches what C# structure in that scenario?

EDIT: As I feared, this does not bode well :
[GLSL array uniform with a dynamic length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519961/glsl-array-uniform-with-a-dynamic-length)

> Make multiple shaders, one for each number of potential items in the
> linked lists you want to support. GLSL does not support variable sized
> arrays. The only other solution is to create arrays with the largest
> size you'll ever use.

Comment: Both could be tackled with a "hack": instead of a list you will use an array of fixed maximum size .. doesn't need to be all used but always big enough to cover all your use cases. Then instead of the typed field you use a `byte[]` big enough to cover all your cases (e.g. long = 8 bytes, Vector3 = 12 bytes) etc .. you would rather have a single type then with a type index and some bytes to be converted from and to that type ... if those conversations will be efficient though is another question :'D

Comment: @derHugo I also came accross this FieldOffset C# decorator : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126781/c-union-in-c-sharp what do you think?

Comment: GPU shaders are very simple, and does not deal well with multiple levels of indirection, as is needed for polymorphic types and linked lists. While there are ways to provide similar functionality, but it might not be a good idea. Note that it is very difficult to provide recommendations without any idea of the problem you are trying to solve, or even if it is a problem well suited for GPUs.

Comment: @JonasH you are right. But for now I don't want to to pollute my question. So either you or _derHugo can write an actual answer paraphrasing your comments and I'll mark it as correct. Also please note that I have just tested the use of [FieldOffset(0)] (as suggested in my comment's link) and it works for simulating a union type.